# Loading a csv file as a ts

Tags: r, csv, time-series

Below are monthly prices of a particular stock;

```
Year    Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2008    46.09   50.01   48      48      50.15   43.45   41.05   41.67   36.66   25.02   22.98   22
2009    20.98   15      13.04   14.4    26.46   14.32   14.6    11.83   14      14.4    13.07   13.6
2010    15.31   15.71   18.97   15.43   13.5    13.8    14.21   12.73   12.35   13.17   14.59   15.01
2011    15.3    15.22   15.23   15      15.1    14.66   14.8    12.02   12.41   12.9    11.6    12.18
2012    12.45   13.33   12.4    14.16   13.99   13.75   14.4    15.38   16.3    18.02   17.29   19.49
2013    20.5    20.75   21.3    20.15   22.2    19.8    19.75   19.71   19.99   21.54   21.3    27.4
2014    23.3    20.5    20      22.7    25.4    25.05   25.08   24.6    24.5    21.2    20.52   18.41
2015    16.01   17.6    20.98   21.15   21.44   0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I want to decompose the data into seasonal and trend data but I am not getting a result.
How can I load the data as a "ts" class data so I can decompose it?

Comment: Er, is this an `r` question? Or `Python`? Or something else?

Comment: How can I solve this error                                                                                                                                   Error in decompose(se) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

Comment: Please answer my question.

Comment: What have you tried already? You said you "are not getting a result". Please post the code that didn't work. SO is **not** a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `tidyr`, which is fairly accessible.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
data %>% gather(month, price, -Year) %>% # 1 row per year-month pair, name the value "price"
  mutate(synth_date_txt= paste(month,"1,",Year), # combine month and year into a date string
         date=as.Date(synth_date_txt,format="%b %d, %Y")) %>% # convert date string to date
  select(date, price) # keep just the date and price

#          date price
# 1  2008-01-01 46.09
# 2  2009-01-01 20.98
# 3  2010-01-01 15.31
# 4  2011-01-01 15.30
# 5  2012-01-01 12.45
```

This gives you an answer with date format (even though you didn't specify a date, just a month and year).  It should work for your time series analysis, but if you really need a timestamp you can just use `as.POSIXct(date)`

Comment: How will I apply the code above based on the code I pasted below?

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

The program is R and below is the code I have tried.

```
sev=read.csv("X7UPM.csv")
se=ts(sev,start=c(2008, 1), end=c(2015,1), frequency=12)
se
se=se[,1]
S=decompose(se)
plot(se,col=c("blue"))
plot(decompose(se))
S.decom=decompose(se,type="mult")
plot(S.decom)
trend=S.decom$trend
trend
seasonal=S.decom$seasonal
seasonal
ts.plot(cbind(trend,trend*seasonal),lty=1:2)
plot(stl(se,"periodic"))
```

Comment: this should go as an edit to your question, not an answer to your question